# GOBIN root setting with var multi GOPATH in .zshrc config

Tags: zshrc

```
export GOPATH=~/mygo:~/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

I expected the `$GOBIN` equals `~/mygo/bin:~/go/bin` but it is `~/mygo:~/go/bin` instead.
how could I set them a better way? thx

Comment: What is the result that you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
export GOPATH=~/mygo:~/go
export GOBIN=${(j<:>)${${(s<:>)GOPATH}/%//bin}}
```

#### Explanation

Although whatever program uses `GOPATH` might interprete it as an array, for `zsh` it is just a scalar ("string").

In order to append a string (`/bin`) to every element the string "$GOPATH" first needs to be split into an array. In `zsh` this can be done with the *parameter expansion flag* `s:string:`. This splits a scalar on `string` and returns an array. Instead of `:` any other character or matching pairs of `()`, `[]`, `{}` or `<>` can be used. In this case it has to be done because `string` is to be `:`.

```
GOPATH_ARRAY=(${(s<:>)GOPATH)
```

Now the `${name/pattern/repl}` *parameter expansion* can be used to append `/bin` to each element, or rather to replace the end of each element with `/bin`. In order to match the end of a string, the `pattern` needs to begin with a `%`. As any string should be matched, the pattern is otherwise empty:

```
GOBIN_ARRAY=(${GOPATH_ARRAY/%//bin})
```

Finally, the array needs to be converted back into a colon-separated string. This can be done with the `j:string:` *parameter expansion flag*. It is the counterpart to `s:string:`:

```
GOBIN=${(j<:>)GOBIN_ARRAY}
```

Fortunately, `zsh` allows *Nested Substitution*, so this can be done all in one statement, without intermediary variables:

```
GOBIN=${(j<:>)${${(s<:>)GOPATH}/%//bin}}
```

---

#### Alternative Solution

It is also possible to do this without *parameter expansion flags* or *nested substitution* by simply appending `/bin` to the end of the string and additionally replace every `:` with `/bin:`:

```
export GOBIN=${GOPATH//://bin:}/bin
```

The `${name//pattern/repl}` expansion replaces every occurence of `pattern` with `repl` instead of just the first like with `${name/pattern/repl}`.

This would also work in `bash`.

Personally, I feel that it is a bit "hackish", mainly because you need to write `/bin` twice and also because it completely sidesteps the underlying semantics. But that is only personal preference and the results will be the same.

---

### Note:

When defining `GOPATH` like you did in the question

```
export GOPATH=~/mygo:~/go
```

`zsh` will expand each occurence of `~/` with your home directory. So the value of `GOPATH` will be `/home/kevin/mygo:/home/kevin/go` - assuming the user name is "kevin". Accordingly, `GOBIN` will also have the expanded paths, `/home/kevin/mygo/bin:/home/kevin/go/bin`, instead of `~/mygo/bin:~/go/bin`

This could be prevented by quoting the value - `GOPATH="~/mygo:~/go"` - but I would recommend against it. `~` as synonym for the home directory is not a feature of the operating system and while shells usually support it, other programs (those needing `GOPATH` or `GOBIN`) might not do so.